# Tailwind css only for mobile device

Tags: tailwind-css

I want border top on mobile otherwise border left. It is working on mobile but show both on laptop. How to hide border-t on laptop.

> sm:border-t md:border-l

```
<div className="w-full md:w-1/4 flex justify-end md:justify-center items-center pt-2 mt-2 sm:border-t md:border-l">
    <div></div>
                
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To hide `border-t` on laptop just use `lg:border-t-0`

Comment: Thank @Johan Yes, it is working as expected.